# Precaution of shining shoes before traveling

Tags: travel, shoes, rabbi-yehudah-hechasid

**[Rav Yehuda HaChassid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Samuel_of_Regensburg)** (circa 1200) writes in his [will (39)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93):

> לא ימשח אדם מנעליו ביום שדעתו לילך לדרך
>
> you shouldn't shine your shoes on the day you go on a trip.

What is the idea behind this?

Comment: Interesting, what substances did they use for shining in 1200? Maybe ask it on Shoes@SE forum or Quora.

Comment: I think you're mistaking, translating ימשח as shine, it is about softening the leather, not making them shine.

Comment: @AlBerko - I hear you. This translation was based on Rav Moshe Heinemann's understanding of it. Good point in where to pose the question!

Comment: This is a pure and uneducated guess, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but maybe it's because doing is at best a waste of time (they'll get dusty again on the road) and at worst harmful (the fresh grease will make dust stick to them better).

Answer (score -2):

The sefer **[Tav Yehoshua](https://books.google.com/books?id=904_AAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA151&lpg=RA2-PA151&dq=%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%97%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A&source=bl&ots=eWaK9ORdgN&sig=ACfU3U1YzdRgdNFPkwMyRLrgwIARTO9d7g&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie1oOvr7PiAhVrkeAKHYkmD4sQ6AEwBnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%97%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A&f=false)** about "*Hanhagos haAdam*" (how a person should conduct themself) quotes this line verbatim in "laws of keeping your body and soul healthy with clothing and shoes" ***siman* 17**:  **si'if 8th**.

(see line highlighted in all yellow)

[image]

Based on the sefer's placement of **Rav Yehuda HaChassid**'s teaching in "laws of keeping your body and soul healthy with clothing and shoes" perhaps one could suggest that the reason for his teaching is health-related.

Comment: Kudos for finding. But I disagree with your conclusion, see #ט. The text lists precautions without any explanations.

Comment: I'm not following this logic. How does this relate to shining your shoes before traveling?